# How to echo from MySQL the row that contain a city but also the row that are empty in the same field?

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I make use of this query. I want to include in the presentation the rows that have London in the `pou` field, and also the rows that the user have not selected any town and are empty.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE eidos='online' AND pou='London' order by time asc";
```

I tried to add `OR pou=''` without luck. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the MySQL OR clause. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE eidos='online' AND (pou='London' OR pou='') order by time asc";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE eidos='online' AND (pou='London' OR pou='') order by time asc";
```